# Invalid use of List Iterator in c++

Tags: c++

int num = 0;
     list::iterator it;
     for(it = binary.const_iterator; it !=binary.end(); ++it) {
      if(*it == '1') {
       abc.push_back(copyoflist.at(num));
      }
      num++;
     }

Here binary is defined as list binary;
copyoflist is a char type vector.

I am getting this error:
invalid use of 'std::list >::const_iterator'
on the line

```
for(it = binary.const_iterator; it !=binary.end(); ++it)
```

Am not able to figure out what is going wrong. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Do you mean "binary.begin()" instead of "binary.const_iterator"?

Comment: am sorry guys ... looks like i need some sleep ... how could i slip this one! ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const_iterator` is a type, not a property.  You would use it like this:

```
 list<char>::const_iterator it;
 for(it = binary.begin(); it != binary.end(); ++it)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
for (it=binary.begin(); it != binary.end(); ++it)
```

Comment: He beat me by a minute, but only because I stopped to fix the format of the question....

Comment: @James Curran: Because of FGITW, maybe you need to answer first and then fix the question.  8v)  I +1ed your answer too.

Comment: Despite the delay, I think James's answer is a bit better, not only pointing out what to do, but also why the current code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<T>::const_iterator` is a type just like `vector<T>::iterator`. You use either one or the other when you declare the iterator depending on what you need to do in the loop. You always use `begin()`, `end()` or the reverse equivalents for the initialization and the conditional.

```
 int num = 0;
 list<char>::const_iterator it;
 for(it = binary.begin(); it !=binary.end(); ++it) {
  if(*it == '1') {
   abc.push_back(copyoflist.at(num));
  }
  num++;
 }
```